# Android Device Monitor's File Explorer not working with Android 7 (API 24+)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-device-monitor

When I connect my device with Android 7.0 Nougat or when I launch an emulator with Android 7.0 or 7.0.1, android device monitor file explorer shows me a blank screen as you see in this image

[image]
[image]

Every device or emulator running Android 6 Marshmallow or lower works good.

[image]

Is this a permissions problem? How can I solve it? My device isn't rooted and I don't want to root it.

Thank you

Comment: I have such an 7.0 device too which acts the same. Moreover not a single log in the LogCat. (Wich makes developing difficult). How's yours? Or do you have more Nougat devices?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, as the Android-Studio Tag says

Comment: Please answer the logcat problem comment too.

Comment: Logs are coming fine but Android Device Monitor is not working.

Comment: check the answer mentioned below and let me know if its working for you or not. It is working for me now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Android Device Manager, you have to run emulators.
Someone submitted a google
[bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229628).